# Use Integers instead of Strings when creating a Task in Step Functions

Tags: aws-step-functions

How can I create a task with Integer input types as opposed to String, for example say I want to kick off a state machine:

```json
        "SomeStage": {
              "Comment": "Getting busy with Foo Bar",
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.waitForTaskToken",
              "Parameters": {
                "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:ap-southeast-2:1234567:stateMachine:mrFooBar",
                "Input": {
                  "foo.$": "$.foo",
                  "bar.$": "$.bar",
                }
              },
      ...
      "End": true
    }
```

My parameters: `$.foo` & `$.bar`, turn out to be inputs as Strings in the `mrFooBar` statemachine. If I remove the quotes I get a compile error. This issue is very annoying I can't figure out how to get rid of the quotes so that my parameters will be integers in the state machine it kicks off.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do that?

Comment: I ended up using `Strings` and parsing them in my application to `ints`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StringToJson` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) will convert a string input to a number:

```json
"Input": {
    "foo.$": "States.StringToJson($.foo)",
    "bar.$": "States.StringToJson($.bar)"
}
```